# How can I find the index of a String array element using the [Array]::FindIndex method in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

another PowerShell noob question.

I have an array of strings that contains the names of businesses and I am writing a script that iterates through the folders of a directory and compares the folder names to the names contained in the array.  When I find a match I need to get the array index where the match was found.  I've done this successfully for exact matches using the following code:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $targetDirectory)
{
    if($businesses -like "$file*")
    {
        $myIndex = [array]::IndexOf($businesses, [string]$file)
    }
}
```

The reason I use `-like "$file*"` is because sometimes the name of the business has "LLC" or "INC" or something like that, which occasionally wasn't included when we named the folders(and vice versa).  I would like to modify my `$myIndex` line to find these indexes as well.

I'm trying to use

```
 $myIndex = [array]::FindIndex($Merchant, {args[0] -like "$file*"})
```

But I'm getting the error

**Cannot find an overload for "FindIndex" and the argument count:  "2".**

I've tried casting the second argument using **`[Predicate[string]]{args[0] -like "$file*"}`** but get the same result.  I've read the documentation for the method but one of my basic problems is I don't understand the System.Predicate type.  I'm not even sure if I'm writing it properly;  I found an example that was similar but used `[int]` instead.  Maybe I'm going about it all wrong but I feel like I'm close and just can't find the missing piece of the puzzle anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

`[Array]::FindIndex($Merchant, [Predicate[string]]{})` only works if `$Merchant` is of type `string[]`:

`$Merchant` is a string array, works:

```
PS C:\> $Merchant = 1,2,3 -as [string[]]
PS C:\> [array]::FindIndex($Merchant,[Predicate[String]]{param($s)$s -eq "3"})
2
```

`$Merchant` is an array of `Int32`s, doesn't work:

```
PS C:\> $Merchant = 1,2,3 -as [int[]]
PS C:\> [array]::FindIndex($Merchant,[Predicate[String]]{param($s)$s -eq "3"})
Cannot find an overload for "FindIndex" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:1
+ [array]::FindIndex($Merchant,[Predicate[String]]{param($s)$s -eq "3"})
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Works fine when cast to `Predicate[int]`:

```
PS C:\> [array]::FindIndex($Merchant,[Predicate[int]]{param($s)$s -eq 3})
2
```

Comment: Okay that's kind of how I thought it would work, thank you for the clarification.  However I still get the same error even when I try your examples.  Could I be using the wrong version?  I'm pretty sure I have version 2.0